# Floating 3rd element right while first 2 go left

Tags: html, css, css-float, multiple-columns

I have 2 sibling divs that I need to float to make a 2 column layout.

Div 1 and 2 have to float left and div 3 has to float right. Normally I can get this by rearranging Div 2 and Div 3's positions but because the markup is generated by Javascript I dont have the luxury to rearrange them, nor do I have to option to group Div1 and 2 together as a result.

No matter what I try or what clear CSS i attempt, Div 3 always appears below Div 2 on the right side, when I need it on the top next to Div 1.

This is what I have to work with:

```css
.parent{
width:800px;
}

.div1{
float:left;
width:60%;
height:100px;
background:red;
}

.div2{
float:left;
width:60%;
height:100px;
background:red;
}

.div3{
float:right;
width:40%;
background:blue;
height:100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
<div class="div1">Div 1</div>
<div class="div2">Div 2</div>
<div class="div3">Div 3</div>
</div>
```

Is there any way to make Div 3 float next to Div1 without rearranging the markup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay tried to do it with flex box and giving a order property o all the divs.

```
 .parent{
  width:800px;
   display: flex;
   flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.div1{
width:60%;
height:100px;
background:red;
order: 1;
}

.div2{
width:60%;
height:100px;
background:red;
  order: 3;
}

.div3{
width:40%;
background:blue;
height:100px;
order: 2;
}
```

working example : https://codepen.io/shubham997/pen/ExxWYEd?editors=0100

Comment: Oh my actual element dont have fixed height, i added those there for the example so that you can see where its at. The divs are dynamic and can expand or shrink based on feeds so thats not an option sadly :(

Comment: Oh this works, thanks! I didntg realize you could order flex box elements like that. I learned something new.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use flex on parent div and correct your percentage ratio of the child divs so that it sums to 100%. I have given margin-left:auto for the child you wanted to place at right end, which will float on right side even if you reduce the width of other divs. Demo [here](https://codepen.io/AravinthAro/pen/RwwKXOd)

```
<div class="parent">
  <div class="col-left">
    <div class="div1">Div 1</div>
    <div class="div2">Div 2</div>
  </div>
<div class="div3">Div 3</div>
</div>

   .parent{
width:800px;
display:flex;
}

.col-left{
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:column;
  width:60%;
}

.div1, .div2{
height:100px;
background:red;
width:100%;
}

.div3{
margin-left:auto;
width:40%;
background:blue;
height:100px;
}
```

Comment: Sorry if I wasnt being specific enough, My layout has to be 2 column, with Div 1 and 2 in the left column while Div 3 is on the right. I cant have all 3 divs side by side. Thank you for the attempt :)