# 4 sibling elements with variable heights: how to float/flex 3+4 to right, w/o vertical gaps between 1+2 or 3+4?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, css-float

I am attempting to turn a CMS-generated page of four sibling elements stacked atop one another into a two-column layout. Here is the simplified generated markup:

```
<section id="element-container">
   <header id="element-1">Text header</header>
   <header id="element-2">Text subheader</header>
   <div id="element-3">Text validation messages</div>
   <form id="element-4">Form fields go here</form>
</section>
```

I need a left column with #element-1 and #element-2 stacked together, and a right column with #element-3 and #element-4 stacked together.

I cannot change the CMS-generated markup (such as to add more nesting levels of container elements).

In real-world usage, #element-4 will almost always be considerably longer than the total combined height of #element-1 and #element-2, though every so often we need to dump a bunch of text into #element-2, making it taller than #element-4.

A CSS-only solution is called for over something like jQuery manipulation of elements via detach() or wrap() etc, for the sake of avoiding an ugly flash of content being rearranged; and hiding everything until it's manipulated is very much undesirable as well. For our particular application, fast/clean loading is the absolute top priority. However, I'd be able to do some of that type of manipulation to (only) the #element-3 div, as it contains feedback to the user about a failed form validation, so it has display:none and height:0px at page load. So I'd be very happy with a solution that "only" stacks #element-1 and #element-2 directly atop one another at left/top, and #element-4 at right/top—from there I can find a way to deal with #element-3.

I spent all day today playing with solutions like the one in [Floating 3rd element right while first 2 go left](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58508895/floating-3rd-element-right-while-first-2-go-left), which is so close to what I need, but all solutions to questions like these seem to assume fixed heights on the elements, and break when uncertainty is introduced to heights. For example, if you play with the codepen on the accepted answer on that question by making div3 200px high instead of 100px high, you get a big gap between div1 and div2.

Open to float, flexbox, whatever. Thanks very much.

Answer (score 0):

You can pretty easily force a two-column layout by using `column-count` on your container element. This will make the browser automatically divide up the elements into however many columns you specify based on their heights, without leaving vertical space between them.

In your case, with two columns, this will basically automatically ensure `#element-1` is on the left and `#element-4` is on the right. The question becomes where do `#element-2` and `#element-3` fall in the auto layout. If the first two elements are pretty small, element 3 may end up in the left column; or if the first element is quite tall and elements 2, 3, and 4 are small enough, they may end up all together in the right column.

Sounds from your description like we probably don't have to worry too much about element 2 ending up in the right column, so I'll focus on forcing element 3 to the right column. (If the former is a problem, the easiest solution is a `min-height` on element 2, but you can experiment with different options.)

Since element 3 is `display: none` to start, one option you can do is to figure out how tall it should be right before you display it, and then absolute position it at the top of the right column while moving element 4 down by the same amount as element 3's height to prevent overlap. I'm using a simple top margin on element 4 in the example below.

In the example below, the height of element 3 is static, so the logic is simple enough, but in your real case you may have to do something like:

1. run form validation
2. add error messages to element 3
3. set element 3 to `display: block; visibility: hidden`
4. get the height of element 3
5. offset element 4 by element 3's height
6. set element 3 to `visibility: visible`

```js
document.getElementById('element-4').style.marginTop =  `${document.getElementById('element-3').getBoundingClientRect().height}px`;
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#element-container {
  column-count: 2;
  column-gap: 0px;
  position: relative;
}

#element-1, #element-2, #element-4 {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
}

#element-3 {
  display: block;
}

#element-1 {
  background-color: firebrick;
  padding: 40px 10px;
}

#element-2 {
  background-color: midnightblue;
  color: white;
  padding: 30px 10px;
}

#element-3 {
  background-color: gold;
  padding: 10px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 50%;
}

#element-4 {
  background-color: mediumaquamarine;
  padding: 160px 10px;
}
```

```html
<section id="element-container">
   <header id="element-1">Text header</header>
   <header id="element-2">Text subheader</header>
   <div id="element-3">Text validation messages</div>
   <form id="element-4">Form fields go here</form>
</section>
```